# Validate Password with at least a dot

Tags: ios, regex, swift, validation

I know there are many question asking for this, but no exactly this, the are question to try to find the right way to validate a password, using the answers of that existing questions doesn't resolve my problem.

My password need to have at least one special character but the regex for that doesnt accept dot ".", literaly a dot, so, What do I need to put to validate the dot?

Im using this, for Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character and Maximum 15 characters:

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%&? \"]).*(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,15}$"
```

This one doesnt accept dot: `(?=.*[!#$%&? \"]).*`

Comment: It's a horrible, ***horrible*** idea to have a maximum characters limit for passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice: Do not use a regular expression to solve this. Better use a `NSPredicate` for each rule, so you (and other people) can understand what you are doing

```
// 8 to 15 characters
if 8 <= text.count <= 15 {

// Uppercase
if NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", ".*[A-Z]+.*").evaluate(with: text) {

// Lowercase
if NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", ".*[a-z]+.*").evaluate(with: text) {

// Number
if NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", ".*[0-9]+.*").evaluate(with: text) {

// Special Character
if NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9]+.*").evaluate(with: text) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solve the problem, and your are right it looks better and easy to understand! :)

Comment: If I understand well, no need to get the match as a whole, but only to check if matches. Why not using only `[A-Z]` for uppercase then (do we really care what's before or after)?